# How can I make an axios call to my asp.net core web api with a react native app?

Tags: asp.net, react-native, expo

I have 1 ASP.NET CORE application on my desktop(Visual Studio 2019) and a React Native(VS Code Expo) app on my android phone.
I wish to use AXIOS to call some GET web api in the ASP.NET CORE application from my mobile app.

I can use POSTMAN to call the api via localhost, but I don't think my application on my desktop and mobile have same localhosts.

Need some help :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call API which run your localhost on Android Emilatör, you must change proxy settings of emilatör.  I think you deploy your API to a server, after that you can call easily.